# Why isn't mathematical induction a circular argument?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, induction

In the induction step, we need to show the thing we're trying to prove is true when n=k+1, using our assumption that it's true when n=k. But how can we truly prove a thing by using an assumption?

Comment: *But how can we truly prove a thing by using an assumption?* --- You should probably revise the wording of this question.

Comment: We prove statements with assumptions all the time. "If $n$ is even then $n^3$ is even." Every if-then statement has assumptions. The inductive step is also proving an if-then statement: "If $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true."—It's common to worry that induction proofs seem circular, so don't worry that you're at this stage! There are lots of explanations of why mathematical induction is valid on the web if you search. (Ultimately, the formal reason is because it's part of the definition of the integers; but I suspect you'll appreciate a less rigorous discussion.)

Comment: Think of the induction step as like a recipe for a proof that takes you from one step to the next. You know the statement is true when $n = 1$, because you proved it was. How do you know that the statement is true when $n = 2$? Use the proof from the induction step, but with $k$ replaced with $1$, and you should get a valid proof that the statement works for $n = 2$ as well (note: the assumption that the statement works at $n = k = 1$ has now been proven to be true!). How do you then know that the statement works for $n = 3$? Try the induction step again, this time with $k = 2$, etc.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to *also* prove "the thing" when $n=0$, and this is done absolutely, *without* an assumption. (The "base" of induction.) Now, you can assume "the thing" for $n=0$ (which you've just proven!) and prove "the thing" for $n=1$, so now you can assume "the thing" for $n=1$ and prove for $n=2$ etc. - until it is proven for all natural numbers.

Comment: So the *base* of induction is a critical and separate step, not to be underappreciated! Otherwise, you could prove that every number is even! (assume $n=k$ and $n+1$ are even, and it immediately follows that $n+1=k+1$ and $n+2$ are even. (As $n$ was even, $n+2$ is even too!) So the inductive step $(n=k\to n=k+1$) actually works! The problem is the base: $n=0$ and $n=1$ are not both even.

Comment: @GregMartin Wow you're making me question the whole world right now...But at the same time, it makes so much sense (if it doesn't a lot of things wouldn't make sense as well which can be a problem). I'll probably be thinking about it for a while, thank you!

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you! I think I get it now

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks a lot, I found out I've been ignoring the base, that was probably the problem. Also I probably shouldn't use the word "thing" loll

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing that you've missed about the induction, is that it has to be true for $n=0$ case. Without that, you are correct, you only chain assumptions with conclusions, which does not mean that the whole statement is true.

Let me give you a concrete example and counterexample:

**Example.** Say we want to prove that $0+1+2+\cdots +n=n\cdot (n+1)/2$ for any natural $n$. There are two steps involved in the induction:

1. Case $n=0$. Then we have $0$ on the left side and $0\cdot (0+1)/2=0$ on the right side. These two are equal and so the statement is simply true for $n=0$.
2. Now assume that the statement is true for some $n$. We will show that it is true for $n+1$. Indeed, for $n+1$ we have $0+1+2+\cdots +n+(n+1)$ on the left side. This is equal to $(0+1+2+\cdots +n)+(n+1)$, I've only inserted brackets here. But we know what this smaller sum is, because we assume that the statement is true for $n$. Thus the expression is equal to $n\cdot(n+1)/2+(n+1)$ which is equal to $(n+1)\cdot(n+2)/2$ by simple calculation. And this is the form we've expected for $n+1$.

Both steps together imply that the statement is true for all $n$.

**Counterexample.** Now consider the following statement: $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n=0$. I will use a "shifted" induction here, meaning the induction starts from $n=1$ instead of $n=0$ (which we can do, it is the same thing). Lets assume that we ignore the first step $n=1$ and jump straight to "$n\text{ implies }n+1$" step. Then analogously to the example above we have $1\cdots n\cdot (n+1)=(1\cdots n)\cdot(n+1)=0\cdot (n+1)=0$. This implication is correct, even though the statement is clearly false. That's because we didn't consider the initial $n=1$ step for which $1=0$ statement is false.